# Is returning a json object instead an array via REST good or bad style?

Tags: rest, list

I am working on my API and would like to return some stats. Those are stored and collected in code, and I can choose my way to return those.

My first approach was using hash, so my data looks like:

```
{
    'obj1': { 'in': 23, 'out': 22},
    'obj2': { 'in': 33, 'out': 19}
}
```

Is this style acceptable or should I use better:

```
[
    { 'identifier': 'obj1', 'in': 23, 'out': 22},
    { 'identifier': 'obj2', 'in': 33, 'out': 19}
]
```

I like style 2 better, because it provides me a base, when I can actually test the result type for each of values (like 'obj1' and numbers).

Is there any REST best practice solution, where I can read more about that?

Comment: Both arrays and objects/dictionaries are fine. Choose the one that fits your data best.

Comment: It depends on who consumes the api and how - if it's an OO language (say java), the first one will require a more complex object model whereas the second will be straightforward to parse into objects.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it provides me a base". In the first case, "obj1" _must_ be a string because JSON says so. No need to check the type.

Comment: @assylias: The first one is straightforward to parse into a dictionary of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions like these are difficult to answer, because they're mostly opinion based. I'd recommend you to put both solutions on paper, and think about their use cases in the future, even test them out. Which one is easier to handle, which is easier to adjust and which gives you more options if there is a need to either add or remove a functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to try to describe what all the fields of the object that you get back *could* be, you would find it difficult to do that with the approach of:

```
{
    "id1": { ... },
    "id2": { ... }
}
```

This is because the set of all possible IDs is a difficult one to describe.

On the other hand, getting back a list of objects that are of a known type is something that can be described well.

For documenting REST endpoints, I'm a fan of [swagger](http://swagger.io) and its structure.  In this case, the [/pet/findByStatus](http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/findPetsByStatus) call is one such example.

```yaml
  /pet/findByStatus:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: status
          in: query
          required: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
              - available
              - pending
              - sold
            default: available
          collectionFormat: multi
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Pet'
```

And the the definition for the `Pet` object:

```yaml
  Pet:
    type: object
    required:
      - name
      - photoUrls
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
    ...
```

You can see from this that the structure that you will get back is that of a well defined list of objects.

It is much easier to tell a client that they will get a list of objects that fills this structure rather than it is to describe the possible fields that an object may return.

The exception here is that if this list of ids is well known ahead of time and unchanging. That you have three fields for `red`, `green` and `blue` and *always* have no more those those fields, then the object structure may be a better choice.

However, with the examples provided - you are returning a *list* objects and thus a list type structure is a better option for clearly communicating the intent of the code.  Iterating over the list you will have them all - and in the order defined. You don't have to worry about a changing order for a hash/map/dictionary structure on the client. You don't have to force the client to walk this potentially inefficient structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not opinion based, but depending on the situation. The first is a dictionary (unordered, fast lookup by key), the second is an array (ordered, fast sequential processing, slow lookup by key).

What is it that the client will need? And is the identifier a part of the object, or just a key to identify it? If it is a part of the object, it should be included in the dictionary for each object.

Comment: The question is about the data format on the wire. Considerations like performance of different data structures is an implementation issue which shouldn't affect the exchange format. (And what you say is not true in all languages anyway - in JavaScript arrays and dictionaries are basically the same thing).

Comment: The points on whether the identifier is part of the object, and whether order matters, are very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches seem appropriate.

I, however, encountered a situation where iOS Swift developers reasoned that their JSON parser does not like schemas where key names are variable. Because it's a compiled language.

I still don't know how serious of an issue that was ... ))